# Dual Space X* finite-dimensional iff closed unit ball is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

i have an exercise where i have to decide if given statements are right or wrong, and i am really frustrated by this one: Given a normed K-linear space X, the question is: Is it right that the dual X* is finite-dimensional if and only if the closed unit ball in X is compact with respect to the norm topology? I could not find any helpful theorems in the script of my lecture at all and intuitively i don`t really have a good idea why X* being finite-dimensional should depend on the closed unit ball in X being compact. Is there anyone who could help me to develop an idea of why these statements should depend on each other at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answered in [Is it true that the unit ball is compact in a normed linear space iff the space is finite-dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287360).

Comment: PS: If $X$ is finite-dimensional, $X^*$ is finite-dimensional.  If $X$ is infinite-dimensional, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3884051) for how to show that $X^*$ is infinite-dimensional.